# JS - pass _GET variable onclick

Tags: javascript, php

The following snippet currently works, however having difficulties replacing the numeric value for group_type with $_GET['group_type'] which has been passed from previous page which I require to be passed onto sales.php.

```
<select name="group_id" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='sales.php?group_type=2&group_id='+this.value;"
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI: There is no reason to put `javascript:` there. Using `onclick` probably also doesn't make sense if you really want the `change` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<select name="group_id" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='sales.php?group_type=<?=$_GET['group_type']?>&group_id='+this.value;">
```

Comment: You legend, worked as needed.  I tried this earlier except I had used <?php $_GET['group_type']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject it in the php code

```
<select name="group_id" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='sales.php?group_type=<?php echo  $_GET['group_type'] ?>'&group_id='+this.value;"
```